# Error with Mailchimp API 2.0 when number of records > approx 500

Tags: php, api, batch-processing, mailchimp

Using the MailChimp API v2 wrapper from DrewM I am trying to update my list with a  list batch-subscribe on approx 700 rows.

When dealing with up to 500 rows, i have no issues, but after that , the list appears to be updated OK, but nothing is returned.

I thought I had found the answer from this similar post [[Mailchimp Batch Subscribe 2.0 Returns False on 500+ records (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082925/mailchimp-batch-subscribe-2-0-returns-false-on-500-records-php][1])

but the problem remains

I also tried the timeout as suggested, (the script seems to run for about 10 seconds)

```
<?php
//loop through the recordset and create the batch array
 while(!$rscontacts->atEnd()) {

$merge_vars = array(
                'FNAME'=>    $rscontacts->getColumnVal("FirstName"),
                'LNAME'=>    $rscontacts->getColumnVal("LastName"),
                'CONTACTID'=>  $rscontacts->getColumnVal("ContactID"),
                'CONTTYPE'=>  $rscontacts->getColumnVal("ContactTypeID"),
                'ACTIVE'=>  $rscontacts->getColumnVal("Active"),
                'INMAILING'=>  $rscontacts->getColumnVal("InMailing")                  
               );                  
$batch[] = array(
    'email' => array('email' => $rscontacts->getColumnVal("EmailAddress1")),
    "email_type" => "html", // optional, for the email type option (html or              text)
    'merge_vars' => $merge_vars
    );

    $rscontacts->moveNext();
}
$rscontacts->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
//print_r($batch);
?>
...
<?php 
set_time_limit(0);
$api = 'xxx';
$mcListId = 'xxx';
$MailChimp = new \Drewm\MailChimp(xxx);

$retval = $MailChimp->call("lists/batch-subscribe", array(
  "id" => $mcListId, 
  "batch" => $batch,
  "double_optin" => false, 
  "update_existing" => true, 
  "replace_interests" => true // optional, flag to determine whether we        replace the interest groups with the updated groups provided, or we add the provided groups to the member's interest groups
));
  if ($retval === false) {
echo "Mailchimp API returned false";
  }
?>
<?php echo $retval ['add_count'].' Records added'; ?><br>
<?php echo $retval ['update_count'].' Records updated'; ?><br>
<?php echo $retval ['error_count'].' Errors Found'; ?><br>

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082925/mailchimp-batch-subscribe-2-0-returns-false-on-500-records-php
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it !

In the script on MailChimp.php, there are 2 $timeout parameters.

The script was timing out at 10 seconds, I needed to set the call function to a higher value - and now the script, (which takes about 14 seconds to run) executes fine